# Maximum number of communication in 5 ports router

Tags: networking, probability

I want to find a formula with it I can find the number of the communication that can occur at the same time (different combination) in f port router for network on chip.

In network on chip's router there are 5 port and each port has input and output. 
5 is the maximum number of communication that can happen at the same time. Here an example:

```
input 1 -> output 2
input 2 -> output 3 
input 3 -> output 4
input 4 -> output 5
input 5 -> output 1
```

I want to calculate how many combinaison I can have.

Comment: This is really a mathematical question. Each port of the 5 can be communicating with each of the other ports, i.e. 4 others, in both directions, i.e. 2, which makes the answer 5*4*2.

Comment: But in each port the input cannot communicate with other inputs and  cannot communicate with the output in the same ports

Comment: I have excluded the case where it can't communicate with itself. That's why it is 4 not 5. I haven't said anything about inputs communicating with inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only figure out that the question is based on mathematics and has nothing to do with the `networking` and `probability` tags!

As you mentioned

> In each port the input cannot communicate with other inputs and cannot communicate with the output in the same ports.

So, assuming one port communicating via input,

the port can communicate with only 4 output of other ports and not with the 4 input of the other ports and also not with the output of the same port.

So,net communication in this case while considering 5 inputs = 5*4 = 20.

Similarly,for the output case, the overall communications = 5*4 = 20.

Therefore,net communication done= 20 + 20 = 40.

If duplication while communicating is not considered(taken into account), then the total communication for  input & output for all ports= 2 * 5 Combination 2 = 2 * 10 = 20.

Comment: Thanks.Actually, I found 4 sets of combination and each combination has 20 cases. That's why I wanted a mathematical formula so I can calculate the total number of combination for large number of ports.